# C# & Entity Framework : return specific columns from a 3 table join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C# application where I am using Entity Framework to pull data from a database. This is the code I am executing:

```
 var person = new List<Person>();

 using (DevTestEntities db = new DevTestEntities())
 {
      person = (from p in db.People 
                join e in db.PersonEmails on p.Id equals e.Id
                join t in db.PersonPhones on p.Id equals t.Id
                where t.Phone == phoneNumber
                select p).ToList();
 }

 var str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);

 return str;
```

When the code runs, it fails on the select. I assume it is failing because there is a table within the database that is not part of the model. And because there is just a generic select, I assume Entity Framework is selecting all columns from all tables and doesn't know what to do with some of the columns.

What I really want to do is to be able to specify the columns that I want to return to the calling function. How do I specify what columns Entity Framework should select?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

EF will not fail because of tables in the DB that are not in model. It would help if you provided the error. Also, your query will result in selecting all columns from the People table but not the others.

An example answer to your question is this, it selects three columns from different tables and puts them in a new anonymous type:

```
var onlySomeColumns = (from p in db.People 
                join e in db.PersonEmails
                on p.Id equals e.Id
                join t in db.PersonPhones
                on p.Id equals t.Id
                where t.Phone == phoneNumber
                select new {p.Id, e.email, t.phonenumber}).ToList();
```

Comment: I added a type/catch and this is the error I get: Error getting value from 'Claims' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_8225C19C3613ADF7947F67E9872DFD553D7F4F2CBF97DC6A89A4211B09200F73'.  Its actually generated when JSON tries to serialize the object.